# Synpress e2e testing, metamask notification dont pop out

Tags: cypress, ethereum, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I'm writing E2E testing using synpress (a cypress wrapper) to connect with metamask chrome extension. I tested the website manually and all work fine in every condition. But, when running test with synpress something strange happen.

##### Information to reproduce

Frontend app is written in nextjs version 13, and use ethers.js to interact with an ERC721 smart contract in this way:

```
contract.createToken(metadata, selectedAddresses, { from: address, gasLimit: GAS_LIMIT })
```

##### Issue

In test script I simply have:

```
cy.confirmMetamaskTransaction().then((txData)=>{
            expect(txData).not.null;
            expect(txData.confirmed).to.be.true;
        })
```

but it fails because metamask notification don't show up. The strange thing is that if I open metamask manually I can see the transaction request in the activity section, but the notification don't appear so the test is going to fail.

Any suggestion? Why the notification don't appear only in testing and work on manually execution?